# Convert object to single. CultureInfo problems

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

So I have the following line of code :

```
Single xFreq = Convert.ToSingle(param, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Variable param is a System.Object Any reason the result is not the same if the "," separator is used instead of the "."? For example 0.45 is converted correctly but 0,45 is converted to 45... This thing keeps bugging me for the last hour...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what your question is since you explicitly specifying InvariantCulture for parsing the string value - hence "." is used as separator.

You need to specify CultureInfo that matches your input. Generally to parse user input you need to use current culture. If input comes from some other source you have to know what culture it was serialized with.

Comment: Alright maybe i am stupid :P I thought invariant culture could convert regardless of the decimal separator. So in this case, although i can get the current culture i still need a scheme where a user can use both the comma and dot separators at his own will. How is this possible?

Comment: No using both dot and comma separtors at the same time as decimal separator is not possible - there are culures that use both at the same time - one to separate thousands and another as decimal separator. If you really want to do starnge things - replace both dot and comma with dot first and than use InvariantCulture to parse.

Comment: Replacing both dot and comma and using InvariantCulture would be bad. If you start with a number like 1,000.00 it will become 1.000.00 and won't be parsed properly with InvariantCulture

Comment: Sure, but it the closest thing to muku's requirement - "magically figure out correct values for following set of numbers 1,000.11 1,000 1.000".

Answer (score 1):

Because the decimal separator is Culture dependent, as other posts clarified, for InvariantCulture it's "." (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat). You can look at the [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) article for more details regarding other separators for number types.

Answer (score 0):

Invariant culture converts from and to "." like a separator. Instead the string you converting from is not in in ariant culture format, hou need specify string's culture.

Thd basic technique in this case  could be to STORE in invariant culture, but show to user what he wants like a separator, so you will get rid of any culture dependent problem and user will happy to see what he likes to see.

Regards.